# How to retain javadoc while building artifacts?

Tags: java, jar, javadoc

I have created a project using Java in IntelliJ IDEA. I've added Javadocs before the classes and functions like below:-

```
/**
 * Modify the expression to replace the old one.
 *
 * @param function new expression.
 */
public void setFunction(String function) {
    this.function = function;
}
```

But when I "Build Artifact", the .jar file does not have this Javadocs. So when I use this in another project, the javadocs aren't seen.

This is the compiled bytecode of the .jar file:-

```
public void setFunction(String function) {
    this.function = function;
}
```

How do I **retain** the javadocs so that if **anyone else** *uses* my .jar file, it has the documentation with it.

**EDIT**

I have created the jars for classes, sources, and javadocs. But how I will configure them into 1 jar *so that it shows up on Documentation(Ctrl + Q)* in IntelliJ?

[image: Picture of Jar files]

Comment: You use a build tool like Maven or gradle that allows building a jar containing the classes, another jar containing the sources, and yet another jar containing the javadoc, and you publish everything in a Maven repository so that other projects can consume your library.

Comment: how do I code the maven/gradle file to allow me to do so? What type of tutorials should I be looking for?

Comment: The official documentation about gradle, or the official documentation about Maven.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JBNizet Hey, I have built the jar containing classes using gradle. Using gradle again, I generated the Javadoc but it's in html, css and js. Not in jar file. How should I build the jar for docs and publish them? Please help.

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_overview.html